# How do I extract all archives in the subdirectories of this folder?

Tags: windows-7, windows, 7-zip

I have researched this title and the answer of the following CMD file was given:

```
FOR /D /r %%F in ("*") DO (
    pushd %CD%
    cd %%F
           FOR %%X in (*.rar *.zip) DO (
        "C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" x %%X
           )
    popd
)
```

The cmd file works great up to a point. Except it gives a the following message for every file found with "ZIP" extension and asks:

```
Would you like to replace the existing file:
Path xxxxxx
Size xxxx
Modified: XXXXXXX
with the file from the archive:
Path: xxxx
Size: xxxxx
? Y<es> \ N<o> \ A<lways> \ S<kip all> \A<u>to rename all \ <Q>uit
```

It stops there waiting for an input. But it asks each time each a file is unzipped. I was going to modify the above command file with something that checks if `?` is found and then calls to a response cmd file that outputs a "Y" then exits, which would take me back to the original command file to process the next file with the "zip" it found.

I don't know if I'm on the right track but I would appreciate some help. I don't know which program is outputting the `?` and text. Is it Windows 7 or is
it 7-zip that's asking?

Answer (score 2):

#### I don't know which program is outputting the "?" and text

It is `7z.exe`.

The correct switch to use is `-aoa` (Overwrite All existing files without prompt.)

Example:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" x %%X -aoa
```

---

#### -ao (Overwrite mode) switch

> Specifies the overwrite mode during extraction, to overwrite files
>   already present on disk.
>
> ```
> Syntax
>
> -ao[a | s | t | u ]
>
> Switch    Description
> -aoa  Overwrite All existing files without prompt.
> -aos  Skip extracting of existing files.
> -aou  aUto rename extracting file (for example, name.txt will be renamed to name_1.txt).
> -aot  auto rename existing file (for example, name.txt will be renamed to name_1.txt).
> ```

Source [-ao (Overwrite mode) switch](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/overwrite.htm)

Comment: Thanks David - your the man that saved my two fingers for some 10k files. Have a good day.

Comment: @Kennertoy Do you need more help? If this or another answer was helpful to you and answered your question, please don't forget to [accept that answer](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 1):

It's 7-zip that produces the prompt. It looks like the [`-y` switch](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/yes.htm) for `7z.exe` does what you want:

> All overwrite queries will be suppressed and files on disk with same filenames as in archive will be overwritten.

The documentation's example indicates that you should place `-y` after the path given to `7z.exe`.

Comment: Looks like `-aoa` (Overwrite All existing files without prompt.) does the same thing ...